# SvelteKit: How to specify port number on node build?

Tags: node.js, build, port, svelte, sveltekit

I'm trying to develop a series of SvelteKit apps for my business. I want to run them all on the same Windows Server using Node; they're fairly small.

I can deploy the first one (using the SvelteKit Node adapter) fine on port 3000. However, the next app I build & try to deploy wants port 3000 as well, and naturally I get a `Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use 0.0.0.0:3000` error. I can use port 4000 for app #2, 5000 for app #3, etc. This is pretty easy to setup using host headers in IIS & URL Rewrite. However, I cannot find a way to declare a specific port anywhere.

**My question**: How do I specify the port I'd like to serve each SvelteKit project on?

I've seen a few posts & blogs on this... Here's what I've tried:

- Creating a `.env` file at the project root with `CUSTOM_PORT=4000` & a `envPrefix: 'CUSTOM_'` directive in the adapter() in `svelte.config.js`. This simply gets ignored.
- Starting the build with `PORT=4000 node build`. This results in an error: `The term 'CUSTOM_PORT=4000' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program`.
- I've tried variations like `node build PORT=4000`, `node build --PORT=4000`, etc. All produce the EADDRINUSE error.

Comment: Hello.  It depends on the adapter you are using.  For example, the static adapter produces a bunch of files that can be served by many servers, such as Nginx.  As such, how you configure your port depends entirely on HTTP server of your choice.  Now, it sounds like you want to use NodeJS as your production server.  If that's the case, does this mean you are using the Node adapter for Sveltekit?

Comment: @JoséRamírez Yes, I'm using the Node adapter. Will revise post to clarify, thx.

Answer (score 2):

For the Node adapter, you must read [this official documentation](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/adapter-node).

In there, you'll find the [Host and Port](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/adapter-node#environment-variables-port-and-host) section that tells you that you use the environment variable named `HOST` to control the port.

If this somehow collides with other things, you may use a custom prefix.  All is there, explained.

This should be enough to get you going.  I'll just say this:  If you are running various Node servers in the same server, then you'll need to come up with a different prefix for each of the servers, or instead create your own Node server by importing the `handler` module, explained near the end of the article.

The advantages of creating your own server are probably many.  For example, you can set your own logging up, and you can opt for a different configuration system for your Node server, such as my pride and joy [wj-config](https://github.com/WJSoftware/wj-config), where you can easily set your port configuration up per environment, etc.